# Using different colors for the same type of atoms in MoleculePlot3D

Tags: plotting, chemistry

I would like to plot a molecule in 3D and use different colors for the same atom type in the molecule. For example, by using:

```
MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N"], ColorRules -> {"C" -> Black}]
```

all C atoms become Black. But how can I make, for example, the first C atom green, the second orange, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I was suspecting Jason B. had an undocumented option up his sleeve, I will nevertheless post an alternative solution.

```
colors = {Green, Orange, Pink, Yellow};

(* Generate regular plot *)
mol = MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N"]]

(* Extract atom indices of carbons *)
ind = Flatten@Position[MoleculeValue["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N", "FullAtomList"], Atom["C"]]

(* Make colored spheres *)
atoms = MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, radius]} &, {colors, ind}]

(* Replace carbons with colored spheres *)
mol /. {{RGBColor[__], Sphere[ind, r_]} :> (atoms /. radius -> r)}
```

[image: Color molecule]

Comment: This is great! Thanks! Wonder if one can easily change Opacity[] of the spheres. I tried so, but failed.

Comment: You can: ``atoms = MapThread[{#1, Opacity[.5], Sphere[#2, radius]} &, {colors, ind}];``. Just a note: take a look also at @JasonB. solution in which the bonds get the appropriate colors! My solution recolors only the atoms.

Answer (score 6):

This is underdocumented but the `"ColorRules"` option can take both atom indices and patterns.

```
MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N"], 
 ColorRules -> {2 -> Green, "C" -> Black, "O" -> Orange, 8 -> Pink}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to target directly "the second carbon atom" with this approach, as the OP wants? Otherwise, one has to first extract the correct indices ...

Comment: I do not have a simple way to get that, other than something like `AtomList[Molecule["caffeine"], "C", "AtomIndex"][[2]]`

Comment: Thanks, @JasonB. Is there a way to add opacity as well? I tried  x, but it did not work out. x = MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N"], 
 ColorRules -> {2 -> {Green, Opacity[0.5]}}]

Comment: @david1983, use ``Directive``, for example: ``MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["NC(=O)C[C@H](C(=O)O)N"], ColorRules -> {2 -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.2]], "C" -> Black, 
   "O" -> Orange, 8 -> Pink}]``